# Fixing Vue Flash Message in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i try to use Vue Flash Message after my axios post method Vuejs.

This is the documentation 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flash-message

After i install the npm, my script looks like this but not working:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message';
 Vue.use(VueFlashMessage);
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {

    addInvoice: function () {
    axios.post('/addinvoice', this.invoice)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);

            if (response.data.etat) {
                this.invoice = {
                };
                this.flash('Data loaded', 'success');
            } 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('errors: ', error)
        })
},
},  
 });
```

Error message : Unexpected identifier on import Vue from 'vue'
Notice that my code works with out vue flash message code

Thank you for help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel / Vuejs Flash Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519445/laravel-vuejs-flash-message)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. Add the console error to your original thread. Your issue is likely that you're not building this code using Webpack/Mix. The code you've posted uses newer JavaScript constructs that aren't widely supported by browser yet, hence the need to build it.